# Google Sheets: Use ArrayFormula for JoinText for multiple columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I want to Use ArrayFormula for JoinText for multiple columns which have their own ArrayFormulas in Google Sheets. 
My formula works for columns that have plain text values but for some reason Google Sheets gives me an error when I apply it to columns that have their own ArrayFormulas applied to them.

Take a look at the example sheet I've created [HERE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15NRiapQwWEQVrfs1GCzCJZuAGP2aeO8tLfOZEjBLAhw/edit?usp=sharing)

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Your sheet is protected. Also what is the desire result?

Comment: Which tab are you trying to work on? and what is the desired result?

Comment: @Rocky Just updated the sheet. Please have a look.

Comment: @MattKing - Just updated the sheet. Please have a look

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solution with query is helpful for you:

`=ArrayFormula(transpose(query(transpose(C1:D),,2)))`

(Will work faster if you know the limit of the range, e.g. `C1:D10`).

---

For implementing commas between the columns you can use

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(C1:C="",D1:D,if(D1:D="",C1:C,C1:C&", "&INDIRECT("D1:D"))))`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it's very slow and my sheet is very long. 
What about the comma between the cell values?

Comment: I see, I added another formula which implements the comma. I hope this is more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I put this formula in cell I2 on your sample sheet.  It should be relatively fast for many thousands of rows.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(C2:C&CHAR(10)&D2:D),CHAR(10),", "))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I think you gotta revisit the question. I don't wanna deal with column A and B directly. I'm focusing on column C and D.

Comment: I saw that, i figured that you didn't need C and D if I just did it all using A and B since it looked like C and D were just being used to construct the joined text columns and I could just skip right to that from A and B directly

Comment: That's the point. I've also mentioned that in the question which says that I don't wanna use A and B, I wanna use C and D. 
The reason I don't wanna use your formula is that It's hard coding the content of A cells because cell data can change in the future. 
Would you be able to modify it?

Comment: I see, ok, I modified my formula on the sheet as well has here in this post.